# Snowflake: COPY INTO after TRUNCATE loads old data?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm getting some unexpected behavior from Snowflake and I'm hoping someone could explain what's happening and the best way to handle it. Basically, I'm trying to do a nightly refresh of an entire dataset, but truncating the table and staging/copying data into it results in old data being loaded.

I'm using the Python connector with AUTOCOMMIT=False. Transactions are committed manually after every step.

Step 1: Data is loaded into an empty table.

```
put file://test.csv @test_db.test_schema.%test_table overwrite=true
copy into test_db.test_schema.test_table file_format=(format_name=my_format))
```

Step 2: Data is truncated

`TRUNCATE test_db.test_schema.test_table`

Step 3: New data is loaded into the now empty table (same filename, but overwrite set to True).

```
put file://test.csv @test_db.test_schema.%test_table overwrite=true
copy into test_db.test_schema.test_table file_format=(format_name=my_format))
```

At this point, if I query the data in the table, I see that it is the data from Step 1 and not Step 3. If in Step 2 I DROP and recreate the table, instead of using TRUNCATE, I see the data from Step 3 as expected. I'm trying to understand what is happening. Is Snowflake using a cached version of the data, even though I'm using PUT with OVERWRITE=TRUE? What's the best way to achieve the behavior that I want? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm using the Python connector with AUTOCOMMIT=False. Transactions are committed manually after every step.

Are you certain you are manually committing each step, with the [`connection.commit()` API call](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-api.html#commit) returning successfully?

Running your statements in the following manner reproduces your issue, understandably so because the `TRUNCATE` and `COPY INTO TABLE` statements are not auto-committed in this mode:

```sql
<BEGIN_SCRIPT 1>
[Step 1]
COMMIT
<END_SCRIPT 1>

<BEGIN_SCRIPT 2>
[Step 2]
[Step 3]
<END_SCRIPT 2>


SELECT * FROM test_table; -- Prints rows from file in Step 1
```

However, modifying it to always commit changes the behaviour to the expected one:

```
<BEGIN_SCRIPT 1>
[Step 1]
COMMIT
<END_SCRIPT 1>

<BEGIN_SCRIPT 2>
[Step 2]
COMMIT
[Step 3]
COMMIT
<END_SCRIPT 2>

SELECT * FROM test_table; -- Prints rows from file in Step 3
```

> If in Step 2 I DROP and recreate the table, instead of using TRUNCATE, I see the data from Step 3

This is expected because `CREATE` is a ***DDL*** statement, [which are always auto-committed](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/transactions.html#autocommit) (regardless of override) in Snowflake. Doing a `CREATE` in place of `TRUNCATE` causes a commit to happen on that step *implicitly*, which further reaffirms that your tests aren't properly committing at `Step 2` and `Step 3` somehow.

> Is Snowflake using a cached version of the data, even though I'm using PUT with OVERWRITE=TRUE?

No, if the PUT succeeds, it has performed an overwrite as instructed (*assuming filenames remain the same*). Older version of the stage data will no longer exist after it has been overwritten.

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation! It turned out that there was indeed an issue with the manual commits. The fact that DDL statements are autocommitted regardless of the override was throwing me off -- good to know!

Answer (score 0):

Can you check below steps will fit to your requirement.

1. Create Stage table
2. Truncate your stage table
3. Load nightly refresh of an entire data set to stage table.
4. Use merge statement to copy the data from stage table to target table.(In order to merge two tables you need primary key(s))

Make sure your stage table is truncated successfully before proceeding to the next step.

Hope this helps.